# Show that $|v| + |v + w| + |w + z| + |2 + z|\ge 2$ for complex numbers $v,w,$ and $z$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Let $v, w,$ and $z$ be three complex numbers. Show that
>   $$|v| + |v + w| + |w + z| + |2 + z|\ge 2$$

I thought about squaring both sides but things would get too messy. I tried using the fact that the absolute value of a complex number squared equals it's product with it's conjugate, but I wasn't sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:   by the triangle inequality:

$$
|v + (-v-w)+(w+z)+(-z-2)| \le |v|+|v+w|+|w+z|+|z+2|
$$

Comment: And of course you can replace 2 by any other value.

Comment: @martycohen Right, and the implied $0$ as well: $|a+v| + |v + w| + |w + z| + |z+b| \ge |a-b|$.